# List of common Java Exceptions

Tags: java, exception

I have been needing a list of common Java `Exceptions`. I need it for an Exception Helper I'm making. This could help a lot more people than me because it can be used as a reference.

How you could help:

- Giving me an `Exception` commonly found in your code.
- A link to a list if common exceptions

If this isn't a valid question please feel free to remove.

Thanks in advance, Curlip

Comment: I'm a little late to this party, but I've found this list to be helpful, if only for a laugh every now and again: http://rymden.nu/exceptions.html

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier underappreciated comment